# Maya Python How do I make a curve out of multiple collected points in a for loop

Tags: python, maya, curve, bezier

I have a forloop to get all the positions in a list of locators, I need this info to create a curve of all the points. but when I put the cmds.curve in the forloop it creates several curves and when I put it outside of it there only is one curve on the last position in the list.
Does someone have a solution for this?

```
    for locator in state:

        print("\t", locator)
        translate_x_value = cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" % locator)
        translate_y_value = cmds.getAttr("%s.translateY" % locator)
        translate_z_value = cmds.getAttr("%s.translateZ" % locator)


        cmds.curve(p=translate_x_value,translate_y_value,translate_z_value))
```

Comment: Sophie, you're transgressing a fundamental rule on SO, probably because you're new here. We like questions that have been boiled down to essentials. They show everything we need to solve them but they're nice and short.

Comment: When you have lots of code, it is cool to see the whole code but you can segment it to highlight the important parts of it (as you did in your edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to feed your cmds.curve() outside the loop :

```
locatorOrder = ['loc1', 'loc2'...etc]
positionOrder = [cmds.pointPosition(i) for i in locatorOrder]

cmds.curve(p=positionOrder) # draw the curve between locators
```